# how to change the sort order for the collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.
tables:

```
users:
id: integer
name: varchar

posts:
id: integer
title: varchar
user_id: integer
views: integer
```

models:

```
User:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :posts,  dependent:  :destroy
end

Posts:
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :user
end
```

controller:

```
def popular_diary
  @diaries = User.joins(:posts).group(:user_id).order('SUM(posts.views)')
end
```

the result @diaries contains a collection users, sorted by the number of views. in ascending order (ASC). but I need to get a collection of users, sorted in descending order (DESC).

I have tried to do so:

```
@diaries = User.joins(:posts).group(:user_id).order('SUM(posts.views) :DESC')
```

but I got an error message:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ":DESC": syntax error: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "posts" ON "posts"."user_id" = "users"."id" GROUP BY user_id  ORDER BY SUM(posts.views) :DESC
```

Comment: Shoudn't `:DESC` be just `DESC`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pavan is right. It must be 'DESC' not ':DESC'